# There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name hello

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, web.xml, struts2-namespace

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

public class HelloWorldAction{
   private String name;

   public String execute() throws Exception {
      return "success";
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

index.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
   <form action="hello">
      <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloWorld.jsp

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   Hello World, <s:property value="name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

This code i have write for hello World Example In Struts But i am getting Error :

HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name index.

am new in struts  and try to Understand struts Mvc Framw work  But i dont know here am doing Mistake where am Missing this please help me how i will Fix it

Comment: I think you need to extends **com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport** in your Action Class

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the new filter

   ```xml
   <filter>
       <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <filter-class>
           org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
       </filter-class>
   </filter>
   ```

   instead of the old one

   ```xml
   <filter>
       <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <filter-class>
           org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
       </filter-class>
   </filter>
   ```

   unless you are using a very old version of Struts2 (2.0 for example).
2. Your web.xml deployment descriptor is messed up: you are saying it is 3.0, then linking 2.5 xmlns:web.

   If you have a Servlet 3.0 Container (Java EE 6) use:

   ```xml
   <web-app          xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                   version="3.0">
   ```

   If you have a Servlet 2.5 Container (Java EE 5) use:

   ```xml
   <web-app          xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                   version="2.5">
   ```
3. Specify namespace in your package declaration, so when you will add new packages you won't have problems:

   ```xml
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default" namespace="/" >
   ```
4. No need to specify the method in Action config if it is `execute()`, and no need to specify the result if it is `"success"`:

   ```xml
   <action name="hello" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" >
       <result>/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
   </action>
   ```
5. Better using HTML5 DOCTYPE and UTF-8 CharSet if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Struts.xml` you have given

`<package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">` Try after changing it to

`<package name="default" extends="struts-default">`

I Hope this answer solves the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Clean your application directory but most importantly i see that you are missing the namespace.

Sample package entry is 
    `enter code here`

The package name is a logical name that you give , but the namespace needs to be "/" or if there is any other context then that name

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still experiencing these issues, please take a look at my answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628016/http-status-404-there-is-no-action-mapped-for-namespace-and-action-name-l/28270127#28270127).

This helped me after struggling for nearly an hour. I followed tutorials step-by-step and still got the error.

Let me know if it helped. Happy coding :-)