# HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [login] associated with context path [/struts2]

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-namespace, action-mapping

I have learned theory of Struts2 and now practicing. Facing problems while executing project.I searched in Google in many ways but could not find result.Please help me. Below is the code.Please help me friends...

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>struts2</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
      "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>

<constant name="resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login" class="com.practice.structs.actions.LoginAction"
        method="validateUser">
        <result name="success">pages/homepage.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">pages/login.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

LoginAction.java

```
package com.practice.structs.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {
private String userName;
private String password;
public String validateUser(){
    if(this.userName.equalsIgnoreCase("abc") && this.password.equalsIgnoreCase("abc"))
    {
        return "success";
    }else{
        addActionError(getText("error.login"));
        return "error";
    }
}

/**
 * @return the userName
 */
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
/**
 * @param userName the userName to set
 */
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
/**
 * @return the password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
/**
 * @param password the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>

<title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1><I>Login Page</I></H1>
<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="login.action" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="uname" key="label.username" size="20"/>
    <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20"/>
    <s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

homepage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<H2><I>Welcome</I></H2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

change your code like this

```
 <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login" class="com.practice.structs.actions.LoginAction"
            method="validateUser">
            <result name="success">pages/homepage.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">pages/![enter image description here][1]login.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>


<s:form action="login" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="uname" key="label.username" size="20"/>
    <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20"/>
    <s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center"/>
</s:form>
```

your action name in form is action.login and in struts.xml is login both should be same and also add the namespace

Comment: But getting same error.[XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
[XmlConfigurationProvider] Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
[XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
[XmlConfigurationProvider] Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts.xml, skipping
[XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]

Comment: please make sure you have added all the library files,and check the location of struts.xml is it under source package

Comment: below are the jars in my application struct2
|
|-src
|-resources
   |-struts.xml
   |-ApplicationResources.properties

lib
|-commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
|-commons-io-2.2.jar
|-commons-lang-2.4.jar
|-commons-lang3-3.1.jar
|-commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
|-commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
|-freemarker-2.3.19.jar
|-javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
|-ognl-3.0.6.jar
|-struts2-core-2.3.16.jar
|-xwork-core-2.3.16.jar

Comment: please let me know if i need to addd any jars or remove existing jars.

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-with-artifacts-in-web-inf-lib-and-use-ant-to-build-the-application.html

Comment: @404 I have read that link is already outdated, also could you explain what they mean by "artifact"?

Comment: In software development life cycle (SDLC), artifact usually refers to "things" that are produced by people involved in the process. Examples would be design documents, data models, workflow diagrams, test matrices and plans, setup scripts, ... like an archaeological site, any thing that is created could be an artifact.

Comment: @404 Did they refer to SDLC or what is you are composing songs?

Comment: As per Project structure (above image) i have added all jars correctly but still i could not find root cause.Please check above code and provide solution.

Comment: please give the complete error list.hope you already changed the code according to my suggestion

Comment: INFO  [TomcatDeployer] undeploy, ctxPath=/struts2, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp3795815829038544849struts2-exp.war/
INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/struts2, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp8150709624299411222struts2-exp.war/
INFO  [XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
INFO  [XmlConfigurationProvider] Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
INFO  [XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
INFO  [XmlConfigurationProvider] Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts.xml, skipping

Comment: [XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
[AbstractBeanSelectionProvider] Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)
[AbstractBeanSelectionProvider] Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ActionFactory)
[AbstractBeanSelectionProvider] Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ResultFactory)
[AbstractBeanSelectionProvider] Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ConverterFactory)
[AbstractBeanSelectionProvider] Choosing bean (struts)for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.InterceptorFactory)

Comment: i am accessing application through this link : http://localhost/struts2/login.action and getting below error msg. HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [login] associated with context path [/struts2].

Comment: in your struts.xml do you closed the struts tag check it <struts>

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit outdated, but I also thought it's worth mentioning, to those who happen to end up stumbling onto this post again and still experiencing the issue; assuming you're 100% sure that your mappings are correct and that your web.xml contains the appropriate filter, try the following:

> 1. Stop your Tomcat server
> 2. Create a "classes" folder in your "WEB-INF" folder
> 3. Move your struts.xml file into the newly created "classes" folder
> 4. Right click on your Tomcat Server and select "Clean" - not required, but would recommend doing so.
> 5. Start up Tomcat again and hope for the best :-)

As a visual aid, your WEB-INF should end up looking something like this:

[image]

If you're still experiencing the issue, double check your struts mappings again, as well as your web.xml

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to respond Ryan's comment nor rate him, but what he says is a valid solution in concrete cases, and I am going to tell why.

**Sometimes the folders you create in a project are not taken as resources of the application, and you have to configure it.**

Let me explain myself with a practical example that may have occurred to some mates who asked for this problem:

When you are developing with Eclipse, maybe you choose another project explorer than the Eclipse's default "Project Explorer", as the "Navigator", for example. 
Using "Navigator" view, you can create folders, but this folders are not package resources (as they are when you create "package resources" with the default "Project Explorer"), so Struts2 cannot find "struts.xml" file to configure the actions. 
So, the only folders that your project will process as "package resources" are the ones under WEB-INF as Eclipse do in "Dynamic Web Projects" by default.

So then, be sure of having all the configuration files in a "package resource".

Answer (score 0):

In your `LoginAction.java` properties you took are

`private String userName;
private String password;`

But in you `login.jsp` you wrote as

`<s:textfield name="uname" key="label.username" size="20"/>
    <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20"/>`

Change

`<s:textfield name="uname" key="label.username" size="20"/>` to

`<s:textfield name="userName" key="label.username" size="20"/>`

I hope this answer solves your problem ...

Answer (score 0):

make the changes on struts.xml file,, add `namespace="/"` attribute in  
like
`<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I had to create a classes folder in `WEB-INF` and place the `struts.xml` file there. Then I placed the `.jsp` files in the web folder and placed `'/'` before the `.jsp` files, for example `/x.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

I was using `websphere` run web application, need to [extra use  struts.xml](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application#step-6---create-strutsxml),

in addition, set `<action name="">` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241015/websphere-struts2-not-going-to-welcome-file), then url `http://localhost:port/{context root}/` shows the welcome-file `login.jsp`.

```
<package name="dst" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

    <action name="">
        <result>/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```